# Excel vba Selecting first visible row after filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to filter a list for a specific value "COUNTRY1" and then select the first 10 rows below the header (from Row 2 Column A to Row 11 Column L) or ("A2:L11")

However because of the filter, the first visible row is not ("A2") but is for example ("A15").

What I would like to do is point to the first visible row, copy the first 10 rows but only to column L. not the entire row. 
Searched some online references but they are quite complicated and with much more details that wasn't helpful.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Code below:

```
wbk5.Sheets("Consolidated").Activate

With wbk5.Sheets("Consolidated")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter
    .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="COUNTRY1"
    .Range("A2:L11").Copy
End With

wbk5.Sheets("TOP 10-C").Activate
wbk5.Sheets("TOP 10-C").Range("A6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With wbk5.Sheets("Consolidated")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter
    .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="COUNTRY1"
    Dim Cols As Range, Rows1 As Range, Counter As Long, RowNum As Long
    RowNum = 10 'quota of ten
    'edit that might help
    Counter = 0
    '/edit
    Set Cols = .Columns("A:L") 'columns from where we need data
    For i = 2 To .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 'from the second row to the last
        If .Cells(i, 1).Visible And Counter < RowNum Then 'if it's visible and we haven't filled our quota
            Counter = Counter + 1 'we're closer to our quota
            Set Rows1 = .Range("2:" & i) ' we can include this row
        End If
    Next i
    Intersect(Cols, Rows1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'from selected columns, from selected rows, only visible cells
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it and getting an error in the "if" condition. Object doesnt support this property or method. I tried removing the IF condition and it works fine but it is copying ALL visible cells instead of only the first 10.